# Partial comparison of 2 strings

Tags: android, string, equals

I'm looking for a way to compare 2 strings partial. I need to clear this with an example.

The base string is "equality". 
The string I need to check is spelled wrong: "equallaty". I want to conform this is partially correct so the input, even not right in a grammar way, is the same as the base string.

Now I can of course parse the string to an char array. Now I can check every single character, but if I check the first 4 characters they will be right, the rest will be wrong even if there are only 2 mistakes. So the check I want to use is that a minimum of 70 procent of the characters should match.

Is anyone able to help me get on the right track?

Comment: Have you considered something like Soundex or Hamming distances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the strings with an edit-distance metric like the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Such a metric basically counts the number of changes needed to make the strings equal. If the number of changes is small relative to the total size of the string, then you can consider the strings similar.

Comment: Thank you. If anyone is looking for the same answer in the future and doesn't know how to create a method for calculating the Levenshtein distance, this is a great source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/FindtheLevenshteindistancebetweentwoStrings.htm